Attempt to access memory once (by the 0th thread out of 32) per warp causes memory access by all the threads
I tried to create a minimalistic reproduction of the behavior I am seeing. Consider the code given below:
#include <stdlib.h>

__global__ void vectorAdd(const float *a, const float *b, float *c, int n) {
    // Calculate the index for this thread
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    float d = 10.0;
    // Perform the vector addition if within bounds
    if (idx < n) {
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx] +d;
    }
}

__global__ void vectorAdd1(const float *a, const float *b, float *c, float *data, int n) {
    // Calculate the index for this thread
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    float d = data[0];
    // Perform the vector addition if within bounds
    if (idx < n) {
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx] + d;
    }
}

__global__ void vectorAdd2(const float *a, const float *b, float *c, float *data, int n) {
    // Calculate the index for this thread
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    float d = 10.0; 
    
    if (threadIdx.x % warpSize == 0) {
        d = data[0];
    }
    // Perform the vector addition if within bounds
    if (idx < n) {
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx] + d;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 1<<19; // Size of vectors
    size_t bytes = n * sizeof(float);

    // Allocate host memory
    float *h_a = (float*)malloc(bytes);
    float *h_b = (float*)malloc(bytes);
    float *h_c = (float*)malloc(bytes);
    float *h_data = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));

    // Initialize input vectors on host
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        h_a[i] = i * 1.0f;
        h_b[i] = i * 2.0f;
    }
    h_data[0] = 10.0;

    // Allocate device memory for vectors
    float *d_a, *d_b, *d_c, *d_data;
    cudaMalloc(&d_a, bytes);
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, bytes);
    cudaMalloc(&d_c, bytes);
    cudaMalloc(&d_data, sizeof(float));

    // Copy data from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Launch kernel with indirect pointers
    int threads = 256;
    int blocks = (n + threads - 1) / threads;
    
    vectorAdd<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, n);
    vectorAdd1<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, d_data, n);
    vectorAdd2<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, d_data, n);
    
    // Copy result back to host
    cudaMemcpy(h_c, d_c, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Free memory
    free(h_a);
    free(h_b);
    free(h_c);
    free(h_data);
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);
    cudaFree(d_data);
    return 0;
}


The first kernel is a basic vectorAdd kernel where I add two vectors a and b element-wise, and store the result in a third vector c. So, per thread we access global memory twice to read and one to write.

From the ncu timing diagram, there are 32.77 K Req of Read to Global Memory (I guess 32.77/2 = 16.38 k Req for each of a or b read)

In the second kernel, vectorAdd1 we read in the memory content of a vector containing just one element in each thread of the kernel. So, based on the previous logic, there are now 3 * 16.38 k (=49.15) Req of Read to Global Memory. (One for the data vector and other for vector a and b)


The third kernel vectorAdd2 tries to access data only for first thread in each warp, so I supposed that just for the access of the data vector, there should not be 16.38k but rather 16.38k/32 given that the memory is accessed once for every 32 threads. But contrary to my assumption, I find that the memory request made are same as that of vectorAdd1.

Why is it happening like this?

in a CUDA GPU, all instructions are issued warp-wide.   in a CUDA GPU, multiple threads reading the same location benefit from broadcast. There is no difference in global access behavior for d between your vectorAdd1 and vectorAdd2.
